# error: no such module 'FirebaseInstanceID' on ios

Tags: swift, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i am trying to run my code and keep telling me

```
error: no such module 'FirebaseInstanceID'
    import FirebaseInstanceID
```

my code in AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  
   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
            print(userInfo)
            return
        }
    
    }
}
```

i think is missing in my pod, i did not  no how to install it to my pod file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated 19/07/2021

remove the FirebaseInstanceID and install Firebase Messaging latest version..

i later solve the issue by installing **Firebase Messaging Plugin**

[Firebase messaging Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

Answer (score 11):

FirebaseInstanceID is deprecated now, that is why this error is coming. Remove **`import FirebaseInstanceID`** from your **`AppDelegate.swift`** and instead add **`import FirebaseMessaging`** because FCM token is now provided directly on the Messaging instance. Now replace the code of **`InstanceID`** in **`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`** with this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    Messaging.messaging().token { (token, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if let token = token {
            print("Token is \(token)")
        }
    }
}
```